# Array partition based on 'contain'

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, partition

```js
var array = [ "123-foo", "456-bar", "789-baz" ];
var selected = [ "123", "789" ];

var partition_contains = _.partition(array, function(value){
    return _.contains(selected, value);
});
console.log(partition_contains);

var partition_filter = _.partition(array, function(value){
    return !!_.filter(selected, function(s){ return value.indexOf(s) !== -1; }).length;
});
console.log(partition_filter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

The output is:

```
[
  [],
  [
    "123-foo",
    "456-bar",
    "789-baz"
  ]
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  [
    "123-foo",
    "789-baz"
  ],
  [
    "456-bar"
  ]
]
```

Why doesn't contain work as I expect although internally its using `indexOf`?

Edit: Works with `filter` but wonder why not contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first approach, I think it is because `_.contains` match exact value between array and the targeted value.

```
console.log(_.contains(selected, "123-foo")); // false
```

My solution will use `some` method from Array.

```
var partitioned = _.partition(array, value => selected.some(select => value.indexOf(select) > -1));
console.log(partitioned);
```

I saw underscore.js also has `_.some` method.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore's `.contains`:

https://underscorejs.org/#contains

> `_.contains(list, value, [fromIndex])` Aliases: include, includes
>
> Returns true if the value is present in the list. Uses indexOf internally, if list is an Array. Use fromIndex to start your search at a given index.

None of the items in your `array` are in `selected`, so the test always fails. `indexOf` only returns `0`+ of the array item *exactly matches* the item being searched for.

Try this instead, checking if `some` of the `selected` items are included in the `value`:

```js
var array = [ "123-foo", "456-bar", "789-baz" ];
var selected = [ "123", "789" ];

var partition_filter = _.partition(array, value => (
  selected.some(sel => value.includes(sel))
));
console.log(partition_filter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```